# How to remove lines containing only numbers in OS X?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to delete lines containing only numbers from a text file downloaded from a Windows machine and stored on my Mac. 
I have tried

```
sed '/[A-Za-z]/!d' input-file > output-file
```

or

```
sed -n '/[[:alpha:]]/p'
```

none of which removes any line with numbers only

When I try to use awk like in

```
awk '/[A-Za-z]/' input-file > output-file
```

it obviously considers the input file as binary and produces a binary output.

I wonder if this is related to text encoding (ISO vs. UTF-8) or?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not `sed '/^[0-9][0-9]*$/d'`?  Any line that contains at least one digit and only digits is deleted?  That's what you're asking for, isn't it?  If the specification of 'numbers' needs to be more complex (decimal points, signs, spaces between multiple numbers on a line, leading spaces, trailing spaces, …), then so be it; you should include sample data as input and the expected output corresponding to that data.  10 lines of input should be enough; the expected output should be smaller or the sample data is not helpful.

Comment: Was the file created on windows? If so, did you run `dos2unix` to fix up line endings, etc. before using *nix tools on it?

Comment: Note that the first command in the Q (`sed '/[A-Za-z]/!d' …`) looks for lines that contain no alphabetic characters and deletes them.  The second (`sed -n '/[[:alpha:]]/p'` looks for lines that contain any alphabetic character and prints them (but a line of punctuation will be omitted, etc).  Neither is an accurate description of what you say you want.

Comment: Jonathan, you're right about spaces between numbers. Any line containing numbers and optionally spaces between the numbers, should be deleted.

Comment: Problem solved. A proper conversion to UTF-8 format combined with 
    
    sed '/[A-Za-z]/!d'

did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete lines that contain only numbers.  I'll assume you mean lines containing nothing but decimal digits.

You also say the file is from a Windows machine, and you're processing it on a Mac. Windows uses `\r\n` to mark the end of a line, so the lines you want to delete may contain a trailing `\r` (CR) character as well if you haven't converted the file.

```
sed '/^[0-9]*\r\?$/d' input-file > output-file
```

The `\?` means that the `\r` is optional, so this should work whether the input file has Windows-style or Unix-style line endings, or even a mixture. It doesn't convert the remaining lines, so a Windows-format input file will generate a Windows-format output file.

A similar `grep` command didn't work, probably because `grep` doesn't recognize `\r` as a CR character. And I did my testing on a Linux system, MacOS has different implementations of `grep` and `sed`, so this might not work exactly the same way.

A safer (and simpler) approach is to convert the file to Unix format first, then use the same `sed` command without the `\r\?`.

```
sed '/^[0-9]*$/d' input-file > output-file
```

Or you can use a simpler `grep` command:

```
grep -v '^[0-9]*$' input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways.  Here's one:

```
sed -ne '/[^0-9]/p' infile >outfile
```

That says don't print any lines automatically (`-n`), but look for (`//`) lines that have a non-digit (`[^0-9]`) and print them (`p`).

Or the same idea with `awk`:

```
awk '/[^0-9]/' infile >outfile
```

Both of those will, unfortunately, also remove any completely empty lines (that don't even have any spaces). To include those as well, you would have to do something like this:

```
# match lines that contain nothing or at least one non-digit
sed -ne '/[^0-9]/p' -e '/^$/p' infile >outfile
awk '/[^0-9]|^$/' infile >outfile
```

or

```
# match lines that aren't all digits
awk '!/^[0-9]*$/' infile >outfile
```

However, for this sort of entire-line selection, it's simpler to use `grep`:

```
# match lines that aren't all digits
grep -v '^[0-9]*$' infile >outfile
```

That prints only the lines that *don't* (`-v`) consist of all digits (`^[0-9]*$`).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for lines which *only* contain numbers.

Comment: OP is trying to *remove* lines that only contain numbers.  That's the same as keeping lines that contain anything else - with the caveat about blank lines.

Comment: `grep -v '[0-9]'` would remove lines which contained `hello1234` though, which is alpha characters too, so I'm not seeing the correlation.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that while you were typing your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first pattern technically should work but will also delete any lines that are blank or newlines. The second pattern is searching for letters/alpha characters while also suppressing output with `-n`. The third pattern is only searching for letters/alpha characters.

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]+$/d'
```

Using the above pattern should find lines which contain only digits and delete them.